# Change ImageButton source based on Theme in xaml

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I want to change the Source of an ImageButton in xaml based on the Theme (i.e. Light vs Dark).  I get a System.NullReferenceException 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when I use the following:

```
<ImageButton
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="10"
        Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"
        Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=add_box_black_48dp.svg, Dark=add_box_light_48dp.svg}"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        VerticalOptions="End"/>
```

If I change the Source to the following everything works

```
Source="add_box_white_48dp"
```

**Can I use AppThemeBinding to change the ImageButton Source in this way**?

*<Edited on 6/4/2022 to show xaml for cases that work and those that do not work.  Also changed the names of the svg files to reflect light and dark cases>*

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.3.0 Preview 1.1

This ImageButton xaml throws the exception:

```
<ImageButton
    Margin="10"
    Command="{Binding CreateNewAccountCommand}"
    Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=add_light.svg, Dark=add_dark.svg}"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    BackgroundColor="#376489"
    CornerRadius="8"
    WidthRequest="36"
    HeightRequest="36">
</ImageButton>
```

This ImageButton xaml works and does not throw an exception

```
<ImageButton
    Margin="10"
    Command="{Binding CreateNewAccountCommand}"
    Source="add_light.svg"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    BackgroundColor="#abdbe3"
    CornerRadius="8"
    WidthRequest="36"
    HeightRequest="36">
</ImageButton>
```

This also works and does not throw an exception

```
<ImageButton
    Margin="10"
    Command="{Binding CreateNewAccountCommand}"
    Source="add_dark.svg"
    HorizontalOptions="End"
    VerticalOptions="End"
    BackgroundColor="#376489"
    CornerRadius="8"
    WidthRequest="36"
    HeightRequest="36">
</ImageButton>
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work cross-platform, refer to `.png` files. These get built automatically by Maui:

1. Each image resource needs Property/BuildAction: "MauiImage".
2. Refer to .png in xaml:

```xml
Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=add_box_black_48dp.png, Dark=add_box_light_48dp.png}"
```

Verified by modifying Maui project's default MainPage, to say:

```xml
<Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=dotnet_bot.png, Dark=dotnet_bot.png}" ... />
```

This refers to a Media item `dotnet_bot.svg`, which (I infer) gets converted by "MauiImage" into a `.png` resource.

---

NOTE: *Maybe* the plan is to be able to leave off the extension. This works on Android, but the image does not show on Windows:

```xml
<!-- Doesn't work currently on Windows -->
<Image Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=dotnet_bot, Dark=dotnet_bot}" ... />
```

Comment: I still get the same System.NullReferenceException at runtime

Comment: Sounds like it isn't finding one of the images. Double-check the spelling of the names. Is it "light" or "white"?

Comment: I tried each one separately and did not get any runtime errors.  Both of these worked: Source="add_box_light_48dp.svg" and Source="add_box_black_48dp.svg".  It only fails when using the AppThemeBinding as shown above

Comment: And what happens if you use .png instead of .svg?

Comment: The behavior is the same.  Individually everything works but when I use AppThemeBinding it gives a runtime exception.

Comment: Given that it is working for me, but i don't have your images, its likely that something is wrong in your code or your images. **1)** Are you targetting Windows or Android or iOS? **2)** Given that `Source="add_box_white_48dp"` works, does `Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=add_box_white_48dp.png, Dark=add_box_white_48dp.png}"` work? **3)** Double-check that the images have Build property `MauiImage`.

Comment: I tried deploying to Windows and to an android emulator pixel5-api31 and both had the same issue.  The files do indeed have the build property set to MauiImage.  I tried the AppThemeBinding as you show and had the same issue.

Comment: Add to question, at bottom, the whole `<ImageButton ... >` you have, when using `Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=add_box_white_48dp.png, Dark=add_box_white_48dp.png}"` as a test. To be sure I understand exactly what you typed.

Comment: I edited my initial post to show the ImageButton xaml I have used.  I changed the names of the svg files to represent light and dark themes instead of black and white

Comment: I created a new Maui App using the default template and added my ImageButton with the AppThemeBinding to the MainPage.xaml and lo and behold it worked. So probably something else in my project has an error when loading the page.  @ToolmakerSteve thanks for your help and responding to my post